# Detect @media queries support in Modernizr 2.0 beta

Tags: javascript, media-queries, modernizr

Does Modernizr 2.0 beta have a way to detect browser support for @media queries?

In Modernizr 1.7 you could test using `Modernizr.mq('(min-width)')`, but that feature seems to be missing in the new version. Is there an equavilant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was added recently for the 1.8pre builds. Grab the master branch at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr for the mq() method

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll give the 1.8pre build a try.